# Ruby HTTP Post containing multiple parameters and a body

Tags: ruby, http, post

I need to post using three parameters and a body which consists of 512 bytes. I can get the body right but I can't seem to get the parameters to take:

```
require 'net/http'

@ip_address = Array['cueserver.dnsalias.com']
@cueserver = 0
@playback = 'p1'

def send_cuescript(data) 

  params = {'id' => '1', 'type' => "20",'dst' => 'RES'  }

  begin
    url = URI.parse('http://'+ @ip_address[@cueserver] + '/set.cgi')
    http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)

    response, body = http.post(url.path, params, data)

   rescue Timeout::Error, Errno::EINVAL, Errno::ECONNRESET, EOFError,
          Net::HTTPBadResponse, Net::HTTPHeaderSyntaxError, Net::ProtocolError => e
   end        
 response_array = []
 puts 'got this value: ' + response.to_s
 response.body.each_byte { |e| response_array.push(e.to_s(16))}
end

data_array = Array.new(512, "\x80")
send_cuescript(data_array.join)
```

I am getting an error from the initialize_http_header. I know there must be a way to set the parameters and the body separately but I can't seem to find any reference to this.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to send part of the params in the url and part of it in the body?
If you have to do this, try

url = URI.parse('http://'+ @ip_address[@cueserver] + '/set.cgi?' + params.to_param)

PS: to_param is from active support. You need to write your own if you are not using active support.

Comment: Thanks Dean, I'll give this a try. I'll try to answer the why question. This is an older device designed for real time lighting playback and control. The developer has developed an API which is based around managing memory and storing data in the most efficient manner possible. His other UI software uses Obj-C and I believe the post method for Obj-C is lower level and he hasn't run into this issue. He just seems to string everything together like this: http://url/set.cgi?dst=RES&type=11&id=1&`512_bytes_here` and that works for him. It doesn't seem to work on ruby…